# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE". I'm getting this error when I'm trying to load the react app on Chrome Browser. What might be the reason that I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome go to [chrome://flags/#enable-simple-cache-backend](http://chrome://flags/#enable-simple-cache-backend) and then enable **AppCache web API and browser backend**. The problem will be gone